# Quais são os padrões de projeto do Android?

Tags: android, design-pattern

Olá, gostaria de saber se existem padrões de projeto para Android(Java), codificação, etc e suas semelhanças, diferenças, qual é o mais usado, pois estou querendo saber mais sobre o assunto e não vi uma pergunta que englobe mais de um padrão.

Obrigado.

Comment: Mas se você quiser um livro a respeito, mesmo assim, eu indico o livro do > Greg Nudelman - Padrões de Projeto para o Android - link: http://www.novatec.com.br/livros/padroes-projeto-android/ Fala realmente sobre padrões de projetos para Android na versão 4. Uma abordagem simples, porém, rica para quem está procurando uma direção nesse sentido.

Comment: Um colega nosso fez um material muito bom com as diferenças entre os padres que podem ser utilizados [aqui](https://medium.com/@FilipeFNunes/android-mvc-x-mvp-x-mvvm-qual-pattern-utilizar-parte-1-3defc5c89afd)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Padrão de Projeto é uma solução reutilizável, sendo um modelo, e não de fato uma implementação, por isso, não existem padrões de projeto definidos por linguagem, ou específicos para Android.

Um padrão de projeto pode ser implementado em qualquer linguagem/plataforma de desenvolvimento.